# How to scraper `JS` dependent content using `Scrapy`

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I am using `Scrapy` for scraping `HTML` content from a [website (proptiger.com)](https://www.proptiger.com/greater-noida/knowledge-park-v/supertech-sports-village-665980). But when I search any element in response, It does not find any element.

There is a text **2, 3 BHK** on the page which can be accessed by `XPath` `//div[@class="spec-value f16"]`. But When I use `response.xpath('//div[@class="spec-value f16"]')`, it does not return the above text.

It is working fine with normal websites like https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide but working on websites like **99acres.com**, **proptiger.com**

Any help would be helpful.

Comment: There are no elements in the document with the `itemprop` attribute.

Comment: if content is generated by JavaScript then you can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `scrapy shell` the itemprop xpath you are searching for isn't available as @furas said, some of the content is generated by JavaScript. You can get at this content by adding Selenium to scrapy. Selenium takes a URL, renders it using a web browser, the scrapy can access the resulting HTML as normal. The code below is a skeleton to get you started using Firefox, but it works with other browsers too. I'd recommend getting hold of Firebug for Firefox too, it's useful for practicing xpaths.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher
from scrapy.http import TextResponse

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

class SearchSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "search"

    allowed_domains = ['www.somedomain.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.somewebsite.com']

    def __init__(self, filename=None):
        # wire us up to selenium
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.driver.close()

    def parse(self, response):
        item = someItem()

        # Load the current page into Selenium
        self.driver.get(response.url)

        try:
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//span[@itemprop="name"]')))
        except TimeoutException:
            item['status'] = 'timed out'

        # Sync scrapy and selenium so they agree on the page we're looking at then let scrapy take over
        resp = TextResponse(url=self.driver.current_url, body=self.driver.page_source, encoding='utf-8')
        # scrape as normal
```

Answer (score 0):

**This tutorial will walk you through these tasks:**

- Creating a new Scrapy project
- Writing a spider to crawl a site and extract data
- Exporting the scraped data using the command line
- Changing spider to recursively follow links
- Using spider arguments

Scrapy is written in Python. If you’re new to the language you might want to start by getting an idea of what the language is like, to get the most out of Scrapy.